# Water transport to the Shoot apical meristem in a seedling

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

I am familiar with how plants transport water from the roots to leaves. Specifically, Water evaporates from the leaf surface, generating a negative pressure gradient which pulls water up from the root.

What is unclear to me, is how water is transported to the shoot apical meristem of a seedling, where there is no leaf above it (see red arrow on image attached).

Are there stomata on the shootapical meristem from which the water can evaporate? Or is there some other mechanism which transports water up here? Thanks.

[image: Seedling]